# PHP (Laravel) Oracle connection does not return all rows

Tags: php, sql, oracle, laravel, apache

I installed Oracle Extension from this [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html), did all configuration and enabled **oci8_12g** PHP extension. After that I could connect to Oracle database and fetch rows.

But problem is that I get different results when I run ***the same SQL query*** (i.e. `select count(*) as aggregate from "TABLE_NAME"`) both in *Oracle server* and *localhost*.

In Oracle, I get *3325508 rows* , but in localhost via PHP (Laravel) I get *1403451 rows* with the same SQL query.

I guess it is related with Apache configuration.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you confirm that the query is being executed by the same server? I mean can you see the database server query log when you execute it from Laravel?

Comment: @HilmiErdemKEREN , yeah, exactly the same server. I checked it.

Comment: Are you executing the queries with the same db user? Or do both users have access to all data?

Comment: @HilmiErdemKEREN the same query, the same db user and the same database. But different result.

Comment: I don't know if I am missing something but, it should be a bug about the extension or oracle maybe?

Comment: Me too.  I'm also confused. Hope someone will give solution.